# Create custom user role (client) that can create another custom user role (employee) of that client

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

Bit of a long question, but I do believe this situation will occur for other people in other contexts.

Our company needs to create an Employee Assistance Program MU subdirectory network site where our company can create user accounts with a custom user role of `client`.

The `client` will be another company needing to use our company's EAP services for that company's own employees.

The `client` must be able to login to the MU network site admin, and add user accounts with an `employee` user role for their employees.

Those `employee` accounts will be able to log in to the front end and view restricted EAP content.

For the `employee` user role, I have use the [code here](https://managewp.com/create-custom-user-roles-wordpress) to create in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
$result1 = add_role( 'employee', __('Employee'),  
    array(
        'edit_users' => false,
        'create_users' => false,
        'delete_users' => false,
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => false,
        'edit_pages' => false,
        'edit_others_posts' => false,
        'create_posts' => false,
        'manage_categories' => false,
        'publish_posts' => false,
        'edit_themes' => false,
        'install_plugins' => false,
        'update_plugin' => false,
        'update_core' => false
    )
);
```

Can I get away with only specifying what is true, and not need to specify what is false?

For the `client`, I have:

```
$result2 = add_role( 'client', __('Client Company Admin'),  
    array(
        'edit_users' => true,
        'create_users' => true,
        'delete_users' => true,
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => false,
        'edit_pages' => false,
        'edit_others_posts' => false,
        'create_posts' => false,
        'manage_categories' => false,
        'publish_posts' => false,
        'edit_themes' => false,
        'install_plugins' => false,
        'update_plugin' => false,
        'update_core' => false
    )
);
```

I need each `client` account to only be able to edit and delete `employee` accounts created by that individual `client` account, and no other company's `employee` accounts.

I gather I could add a hidden custom field to the `employee` user role which will be the `client` ID (added when the `client` creates an `employee`), and this custom field must not be editable by the `employee` role.

I have searched for how to add a hidden custom field to a custom user role, and haven't been able to find a solution.

So, my questions are:

1. How do I add a hidden custom field called `clientID` to a custom user role (`employee`)?
2. How do ensure that when a `client` creates an `employee`, the client's user ID or username (unsure which is best) is added to the new `employee`'s `clientID` meta field?
3. How do I ensure the `client` can only edit or delete an `employee` account (and not other standard user accounts)?
4. Extending 3, how do I ensure the `client` can only edit and delete an `employee` account where the `employee` account has a `clientID` `client`'s own user ID or username?

Thanks.

Comment: This is rather broad and looks more than a project than a question.

Comment: You do need to add `list_users` to your client role so they can manage the user list.

Comment: This is probably a typo but in your `employee` role register, you have a `}` bracket instead of an ending paren `)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clients get added by admins, clients have a parent child relationship with employees which makes filtering easy. So all we need to do is remove anything that doesn't have to do with employees and filter for employees with a certain meta value.

First thing's first, whenever a new user is registered on the **admin** side of our CMS we will assign it a parent of the current user IF that user is a client ( assuming clients cannot assign employees to other clients ):

```php
/**
 * Admin New Employee Function
 * @var int $user_id
 * @return void
 */
function client_register( $user_id ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Grab the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // IF the current user ID isn't 0 and our current user is a 'client' role
    if( $current_user->ID && in_array( 'client', $current_user->roles ) ) {

        // Update the new user with a 'parent' usermeta value of the current 'client'
        update_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_parent', $current_user->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'client_register' );
```

Great, so now whenever a client creates a new user ( of any type ) it gets assigned a parent of whichever client created it. Now we need to filter our user table to only show users with our client parent usermeta:

```php
/**
 * Pre Get Users filter
 * @var WP_Query Object $query
 * @return void
 */
function theme_pgu( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Grab our current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // IF our user ID is not 0 and our current user has a role of 'client'
    if( $current_user->ID && in_array( 'client', $current_user->roles ) ) {

        // Set the query to only return employee roles
        $query->set( 'role', 'employee' );

        // Which has a usermeta key '_user_parent' set
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_user_parent' );

        // and has a usermeta value of the current client user
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $current_user->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'theme_pgu' );
```

Neat! Now we can address the issue of Clients being able to create roles of any type, so we move onto the cleanup process. The below will remove any selectable role when creating a new user or editing a current user to only `employee`:

```php
/**
 * Selectable roles on the new user and user edit screen
 * @var Multi-dimensional Array $roles
 * @return Array $roles
 */
function client_sel_roles( $roles ) {
    // Grab our current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( in_array( 'client', $current_user->roles ) ) {
        $roles = array( 'employee' => $roles['employee'] );
    }

    return $roles;
}
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'client_sel_roles' );
```

On the `All Users` screen we can see the filter views still show other user roles so we need to fix that too:

```php
/**
 * All Users screen filterable views
 * @var Array $views
 * @return Array $views
 */
function client_user_views( $views ) {
    // Grab our current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( in_array( 'client', $current_user->roles ) ) {
        if( isset( $views['employee'] ) ) {
            $views = array( 'employee' => $views['employee'] );
        } else {
            $views = array();
        }
    }

    return $views;
}
add_filter( 'views_users', 'client_user_views' );
```

Finally, one oversight is that the user *could* potentially change the URL to view other users profiles which may not be their own employees, so we need to fix that by adding this little redirect:

```php
/**
 * Stop clients from changing the URL to get to other profiles
 * @var WP_Screen Object $screen
 * @return void
 */
function edit_employees_only( $screen ) {

    // Check if we're on the correct screen
    if( 'user-edit' === $screen->base ) {

        // Ensure our desired user ID is set
        if( isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) {
            $user_id        = absint( $_GET['user_id'] );
            $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
            $parent         = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_parent', true );

            // Ensure that we're viewing a profile that is not our own
            if( $current_user->ID && in_array( 'client', $current_user->roles ) && $user_id !== $current_user->ID && $parent !== $current_user->ID ) {

                // We're viewing an incorrect profile - redirect to clients own profile
                wp_redirect( admin_url( "user-edit.php?user_id={$current_user->ID}" ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'edit_employees_only' );
```

And that should do it. Client roles can only see and edit employees with the parent assigned as their ID.

Comment: That was 99% perfect. :-)  I would never of been able to develop that myself. The only issues I had were: 1) Right after creating the first client Company Admin, I return to `/wp-admin/users.php?id=2`, with `New User created`, but: `Notice: Undefined index: employee in C:\wamp\www\orseap\wp-content\themes\ors-eap-portal\functions.php on line 99`. Line 99 is: `return array( 'employee' => $views['employee'] );`.

Comment: 2) I created an employee account with a client account, but when logging in as the employee, the browser times out and the message `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\orseap\wp-includes\post.php on line 449` appears.

Comment: @Steve - I fixed the views filter, if there's no employees the index in the array doesn't exist so I've added a check to ensure it's set. As for the fatal error, I suggest commenting out function by function to narrow down where the issues lies, I'm not getting that issue using the roles in your question and my functions in the answer.

Comment: Are you using `current_user_can()` with user roles? You shouldn't.

Comment: Howdy McGee, how would I restrict front end content to `employee` and `client` user types? I believe I need to use `<?php if(current_user_can('some_capability') ); ?>` but not sure what `some_capability` should be. I prefer not to use a plugin.

Comment: Honestly, you can pass a role to `current_user_can()` to check against - I'm not sure why @cybmeta suggests not to use it. You could also do what I'm doing in all the other functions, get the current user and check against his list of roles using `in_array()`

Comment: You can not use roles with `current_user_can()`, it may eventually works but you can not trust in the result. That function is intended to check current user capabilities. You can find that information in the Codex. There are also tickets in trac about this.

Comment: Hi @cybmeta. I've uploaded my theme to a staging website, but when I go to create an `employee` or `client company admin`, those roles are not there to select. The staging website is a MU site, and the theme is active not in the main site, but in a subdirectory MU site. This is how we wish to have it on the production site too (a MU site).

Comment: Hi @cybmeta, how do I restrict Pages to `client` or `employee` user account types? Thanks.

Comment: @Steve The comment section isn't really for extended discussion or additional questions. I would suggest creating a new WPSE question ( or search the site for page restrictions by role ) and wait for someone to post a solid insightful answer ( Comments have a character limit and are poor format to post code snippets ). As a clarification note, please add in whether the restriction would be on the front-end, back-end, or both. Thanks & Good Luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, logged in as Client and I can add new user, but cannot see the user list of users added.